# Coupled modified Bessel differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, fluid-dynamics

When linearsing and expanding in normal modes the Navier-Stokes equations in cylindrical coordinates, two coupled modified Bessel equations are obtained for the radial and the azimuthal velocity,

$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 u}{\mathrm{d} r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} r} - \left(\tilde{k}^2 + \frac{m^2 +1}{r^2} \right)u = \frac{2 i m}{r^2} v + A \, k \, I_{m-1}(k r) - A \, \frac{m \, I_m(k r)}{r}$,

$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 v}{\mathrm{d} r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} r} - \left(\tilde{k}^2 + \frac{m^2 +1}{r^2} \right)v = - \frac{2 i m}{r^2} u + A \, i \, m \, I_m (kr)$,

where $u$ and $v$ are the radial and the azimuthal velocities respectively, $k$ is the axial wavenumber and $\tilde{k}$ is another axial wavenumber modified by the viscosity, $A$ is a constant, $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the azimuthal number and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Since the $u$ and $v$ have to be bounded, I suppose that the solution is a linear combination of first order modified bessel functions ($K_m(x)$ diverges at $x = 0$), as for the axisymmetric case ($m = 0$), although I do not see an easy way to solve both equations since they are coupled. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Diagonalize the problem and find the Green's function.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the pairs $z^\pm=\pm iu+ v$ should help solving the problem: denoting $L[.]$ the L.H.S Bessel differential operator
\begin{align}
L[z^+]&=-\frac{2m}{r^2}z^++iA\left(kI_{m-1}(kr)-\frac{mI_m(kr)}{r}+kI_m(kr)\right)\\
L[z^-]&=\frac{2m}{r^2}z^--iA\left(kI_{m-1}(kr)-\frac{mI_m(kr)}{r}-kI_m(kr)\right)
\end{align}
Then, we have to solve (if I am not wrong)
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2z^{\pm}}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dz^\pm}{dx}-\left( 1+\frac{(m\mp 1)^2}{x^2} \right)z^\pm=\pm iA\frac{k}{\bar{k}^2}\left[I'_m(ax)\pm I_m(ax)\right]
\end{equation} 
where $x=\bar{k}r$ and $a=\tfrac{k}{\bar{k}}$.

Comment: This works actually! Thanks! However, now my doubt is about the particular solution of both equations. Indeed, $z^{-} = B I_{m+1}(\tilde{k} r) + z^{-}_{p}$. Should I assume a particular solution of the form $z^{-}_p = \lambda_1 I_m(kr) + \lambda_2 I_{m-1}(kr) + \lambda_3 I_{m+1}(kr)$?

Comment: This is probably much more involved, principally because the arguments of the Bessel functions are different ($k\ne\bar{k}$). Perhaps, as a first step, you may use the [multiplication theorem](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.44.E1) to decompose $I_m(ax)$ and $I'_m(ax)$ as sums over $I_{m+p}(x)$, with $p=0,1,2\cdots$. Then try to integrate the ODE as a superposition of solution for each term of the series.